# Views : blank pages when too much results

Tags: views, 9

I'm using the Geolocation module to display a map of locations. I have about 550 locations to display currently and I need them all on my map. But whenever I try to show more than 300 results the page just comes out blank.

The marker's tooltip contains data for the location clicked on. One of these data is an image lazyloaded through Blazy. Adding the image to the template reduces the number of results I can display to about a maximum of 50 before the page goes blank.

Weirdly, browsing the website with  Firefox allows me to load way more results than browsing with any other browser.

I don't have much leads on how to solve the issue other than it is very likely performance related. Any insight on how to display my whole 500+ locations and their image  without getting a blank page?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the browser console log?

Comment: @cilefen Yup, nothing of interest here

Comment: Is a complete HTML page returned?

Comment: I mean, nah, it's the good old blank page blank html (appart from the automatic "<html><body></body></html>" generated by  the browser. No log, no nothing. Changing the max nb of displayed elements fixes the page but that's the issue  there.